# Merging smaller polygons into bigger surrounding polygons in QGIS

Tags: qgis, shapefile, polygon, merge

I am using QGIS 3.34.2 (Prizren). I am using a village-level shapefile which I downloaded from [SHRUG](https://www.devdatalab.org/shrug). I have to use only the villages in West Bengal for an analysis. Furthermore, I need to combine the villages into gram-panchayats (GP). A GP is a group of villages determined by the State Election Commission. After dissolving the file and coming up with the necessary groupings, I find that there is a problem with it.

[image]

As shown in the figure above, the highlighted polygons are 2 separate GPs. The smaller polygon within each is a village which was not dissolved into the surrounding GP. The issue is that the smaller villages are administratively a part of the adjoining GP and not the GP in which they are located in the figure. For instance, villages *x* and *y* are a part of GP *A* and *B*, respectively. However, the figure above shows that village *x* is surrounded by GP *B*, and village *y* is in GP *A*. How do I merge the village so that the small villages are merged into the GP surrounding it? Would it be possible to keep the information of the two GPs separately in the attributes table after merging?

Comment: Hi @Ramandeep you have several questions there. It would help if you narrow it down to a single question. And, if required, as the other questions in a seperate entry. I'm sure you have thought of that but if you want to group your areas by "GP", you may induce errors when assigning them to a different "GP". I could imagine these small encircled areas are cities surrounded by less denesely populatet area if this has to do with voting districts. If you dissolve and then aggregate other values like population/economic output/... this dissolving would induce a lot of error.

Comment: If your villages are always smaller than your GPs, you might see if selecting them by area below a certain size and then using the Eliminate Selected Polygons tool to merge them into the larger area or largest shared boundary might get you most of what you want.